# Is it possible to dynamically set one xml node's value with other xml node's value without XSLT or programming language?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a following xml

```
<Payload>
  <Setting Name="first"><![CDATA[<p>Hi hello Hw r u?</p><p>We are fine</p><p>Hi babeeee!!!!</p>]]></Setting>
  <Setting Name="second"><Setting>
</Payload>
```

Is it possible to dynamically set the value of second Setting tag to the value of the first Setting tag without XSLT or programming language (C#, Java etc) ?

Comment: Your very question implies a language, though. What, if no language is involved, will do the setting?

Comment: @Utkanos sorry, didn't fully understand your comment. By my question  i mean, if i can only with instruction in xml file solve the task. Could you please correct me, if i am wrong.

Comment: There have been some attempts like XLink and XPointer, there is also XInclude. None of that, however, has a broad support.

Comment: @Martin Honnen what about such an example of referencing ?

 <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>
<!DOCTYPE author [
  <!ELEMENT author (#PCDATA)>
  <!ENTITY js "Jo Smith">
]>
<author>&js;</author> 

Is it a possible solution ?

Comment: DTDs allow you to define entities and reference them repeatedly elsewhere but there is no mechanism that allows you to write an entity that references the first `Setting` element you have. Additionally, DTDs are nowadays disabled by default due to security settings. So it, like XInclude, XLink, XPointer, depends all on the parser you want to use.

Comment: @Martin Honnen  thanks, could you please suggest other type of reusing

Comment: You might find tools like Powershell or xmlstarlet that are sufficiently simple that you don't consider them to be a "programming language", but the less they look like a programming language, the less you can do with them.

Comment: @Michael Kay, thanks